# Как вычислять Ватт/часы по поступающим Вольт/Амперам в Python?

Tags: python, время, arduino

По последовательному порту несколько раз в секунду скрипт получает строку из которой я выделяю Ватты, но я не могу сообразить как интегрировать время, чтобы получить Ватт/часы. Правильно ли будет считать вот так:

```
import time
SerData = WattMeter.readline()#предыдущее сообщение
start = time.time_ns()
SerData = WattMeter.readline()#последнее сообщение с ваттами от Ардуино
end = time.time_ns()
mSec = (end - start)/ 1000000
mWattSec =  mSec * int(SerData.decode()) 
WattHour += mWattSec / 3600000 
kWh = WattHour / 1000
```

?

Comment: Может и правильно. А что такое SerData?

Comment: `Ватт*часы`  !!!

Comment: U * I = W (электрическая мощность, Ватт). Вт * ч (потраченная энергия, они же Дж если привести к Вт * сек) = W * T = x. Подставляем W, получаем x = U * I * T = Вольты * Амперы * Время. Если время задано в часах, то так и подставляете, получатся именно Ватт * часы. Если в других единицах, то переводите их в часы.

Comment: 1. time_ns() возвращает наносекунды, чтоб перевести в секунды нужно делить на 1.000.000.000, а не 1.000.000 как у вас.

Comment: ого! спасибо, а есть метод более подходящий для интервалов в 0.1-0.15 секунды?

Comment: Интервал довольно большой. Тут милисекундного времени хватит. А наносекунды в питоне не дают существенной точности при таких интервалах и могут плавать ±100 в зависимости от загрузки ОС.

Answer (score 0):

Счетчик Ватт*часов с точностью наносекунд нужно делать в ОС реального времени. Рассчитывать в прерывании самой ардуины а на компьютер передавать уже посчитанное значение.

Например бытовые счетчики выдают один импульс в единицу Втч. Посчитали импульсы - узнали потребление.

В случае ардуины можно выдавать сообщение с мгновенным значением и накопленным интегральным значением.